# Why struts 1.0 convert empty string to 0L?

Tags: java, struts-1

I have a form:

```
public class ActionLogForm extends ActionForm {
    private Long ContractId;
    public Long getContractId() {
        return contractId;
    }

    public void setContractId(Long ContractId) {
        this.contractId= contractId;
    }
}
```

and in JSP, I have:

```
<html:hidden property="contractId" styleId="contractId" value="" />
```

Why `actionLogForm.getContractId()` in my dao have `0L`?
How can I change default with this to null?

Comment: Does your actual code have a method named `getcontractId` or is it `getContractId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Struts](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/userGuide/building_controller.html) ActionForm and DynaActionForm documentations clearly specifies.

> If you do not supply an initial
>   attribute, numbers will be initialized
>   to 0 and objects to null.

I know you're using a `Long` but (even since before Autoboxing) the following data types are "boxed".

- Integer/int
- Double/double
- Long/long
- Float/float
- Boolean/boolean
- Short/short

When Struts sees an `Number` object subtype, instead of its primitive type, it autoboxes it for you, hence why you have a default value of `0`. It has its own implementation of the primitive/object type conversion (in `BeanUtils`). The reason for it, is for backward compatibility with the older Struts 1 versions (which ran on JDK 1.4 and JDK 1.3).

I hope this helps.